# In Star Trek Bridge Crew (VR), what controls Shield Recharge?

Tags: star-trek-bridge-crew

In Star Trek Bridge Crew, the shields have to go down before you start taking damage to your hull. The shields stay at 0% for a long time, but eventually they decide it's time to recharge, and they go from 0% to 100% in a few seconds.

What determines how long they stay down before recharging? Is it an amount of time not being hit by enemy fire? Does shield power or whether the shields are up/down have any impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shields begin to recharge 75 seconds after the most recent damage dealt to them, regardless of the amount of power routed to shields.** You cannot speed this up by manually lowering & raising shields or traveling via impulse or warp to another location.

This has been tested by a few different players, who posted their results on the Ubisoft forums:

- [Aegis Shield Recharge Rates - For the last time...](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1739045-Aegis-Shield-Recharge-Rates-For-the-last-time?p=12896410&viewfull=1#post12896410)
- [Understanding Engineering](https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1680511-Understanding-Engineering?p=12700460&viewfull=1#post12700460)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the other answer is correct. I have found that if manually lowered, the recharge wait is about a minute.

I tested it with a stop watch. I tested this theory by re-raising raising shields at ten sec intervals starting at 40. At 60 they came back on when manually lowered. On the other hand when I allowed the shields raise on their own I found varying results.

I'm pretty positive the two leading primary extraneous variable that prevent the shields from raising faster are

1. Being fired on while shields are active even though they are lowered, and
2. The percentage of damage taken to the sub system shield emitters

Answer (score 1):

This is unverified, but I found a possible answer to my own question on [this site](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1680511-Understanding-Engineering).

> Shield recharge is not impacted by power. It takes 115 seconds from either the shields being lowered (either by the tactical station turning them off or by damage) or since the last hit taken on the shields for them to recharge back to 100%, which will take a couple of seconds.